# Convert from one date-time format to a different date-time format

Tags: perl, unix-timestamp

I want to convert a time which is taken as an argument to the Perl script into a different format.

The input is of the form `yyyyMMddHHmmss` (e.g. `20190101235010`).

The output should be of of the form `yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss` (e.g. `2019-01-01-23:50:10`).

It would be better if solution doesn't use Perl Modules (except POSIX).

Comment: Have you tried solving this yourself? Why do you not want to use any modules? What timezone is the time in that you are getting? The format you want is non-standard, but only differs from the format you seem to be getting as input by a bunch of dashes and colons.

Comment: `20190101235010` is not "unix format". There's no such thing, and people will probably think you mean unix epoch time (the number of seconds since the start of Jan 1st, 1970, UTC)

Comment: As far as I can tell, despite saying it twice, you're not trying to convert to UTC time or any other time zone. Your simply want to change the format of the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core module [Time::Piece](https://perldoc.pl/Time::Piece) does this easily.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

# if input is the format you specified:
my $input = '20190101235010';
my $time = Time::Piece->strptime($input, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S');
print $time->strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'), "\n";

# if input is a unix epoch timestamp:
my $input = time;
my $time = gmtime $input;
print $time->strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S'), "\n";
```

Comment: Unless the OP has to deal with date-times in the year 641,768 with second accuracy, `20190101235010` is not a unix epoch time.

Comment: @ikegami I hope not! Though it could be a millisecond epoch from Java/JS, that seems unlikely. I was just providing for a couple of possible things the OP meant.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few alternatives that will do quite nicely:

```
my $output =
    sprintf "%s-%s-%s-%s:%s:%s",
       unpack 'a4 a2 a2 a2 a2 a2',
          $input;
```

```
my $output = $input =~ s/^(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)\z/$1-$2-$3-$4:$5:$6/sr;
```

```
my $output = $input =~ /^(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)\z/s
  ? "$1-$2-$3-$4:$5:$6"
  : die("Bad input\n");
```